# Sort by one column's values, keeping rows grouped by another column's value

Tags: python, sorting, pandas

I have two (hundreds) df's that are generated and then concatenated, which I would then like to sort while keeping the rows with identical column `D` names in the original order:

```
In [120]: df_list[0]
Out[120]:

   A         B         C         D
0  0.564678  0.598355  0.606693  MA0835
1  0.066291  0.063587  0.662292  MA0835
2  0.000000  0.000000  0.010758  MA0835
3  0.000000  0.000000  0.097895  MA0835
4  0.000000  0.000000  0.136468  MA0835

In [121]: df_list[1]
Out[121]:

   A         B         C         D
0  0.628844  0.614492  0.570333  MA1002
1  0.317790  0.293189  0.239368  MA1002
2  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  MA1002
3  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  MA1002
4  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  MA1002

In [122]: df = pd.concat(df_list[0:2])

In [122]: df
Out[122]:
   A         B         C         D
0  0.564678  0.598355  0.606693  MA0835
1  0.066291  0.063587  0.662292  MA0835
2  0.000000  0.000000  0.010758  MA0835
3  0.000000  0.000000  0.097895  MA0835
4  0.000000  0.000000  0.136468  MA0835
0  0.628844  0.614492  0.570333  MA1002
1  0.317790  0.293189  0.239368  MA1002
2  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  MA1002
3  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  MA1002
4  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  MA1002
```

Standard sorting produces:

```
In [125]: df.sort_values('A',ascending=False)
Out[125]:
   A         B         C         D
0  0.628844  0.614492  0.570333  MA1002
0  0.564678  0.598355  0.606693  MA0835
1  0.317790  0.293189  0.239368  MA1002
1  0.066291  0.063587  0.662292  MA0835
2  0.000000  0.000000  0.010758  MA0835
3  0.000000  0.000000  0.097895  MA0835
4  0.000000  0.000000  0.136468  MA0835
2  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  MA1002
3  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  MA1002
4  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  MA1002
```

However, I would like to sort on `A` and keep the row-groupings as specified by `D`.  This is the desired output:

```
   A         B         C         D   
0  0.628844  0.614492  0.570333  MA1002
1  0.317790  0.293189  0.239368  MA1002
2  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  MA1002
3  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  MA1002
4  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  MA1002
0  0.564678  0.598355  0.606693  MA0835
1  0.066291  0.063587  0.662292  MA0835
2  0.000000  0.000000  0.010758  MA0835
3  0.000000  0.000000  0.097895  MA0835
4  0.000000  0.000000  0.136468  MA0835
```

Do I need to work with `groupby`, or is there another sorting/grouping technique I am unfamiliar with?

Comment: Is the absolute order of "D" important or would it be acceptable if the order was alphabetical?

Comment: The 5 rows associated with each `D` should be kept in the same order, as the index for each `D` indicates.

Comment: My fault, I wasn't clear. Does the order of each 5 row grouping in 'D' matter? For example would it be acceptable if the group of MA0835 came before the group of MA1002?

Comment: I could be more clear, as well. In this case, MA1002 must come first, because we are sorting on A and 0.62 > 0.56

Comment: Why not `pd.concat(df_list[0:2]).sort_values(by='D', ascending=False)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `keys` argument in `pd.concat`

```
keys = [(df.A.iloc[0], i) for i, df in enumerate(list_of_dfs)]
pd.concat(list_of_dfs, keys=keys) \
    .sort_index(ascending=[False, True, True]) \
    .reset_index(drop=True)
```

[image]

Comment: This gets me closer.  I was not clear enough, though - in the end, the order of each 'block' of D doesn't matter, so long as the whole df is sorted on the `A` value at each index 0

Comment: The new answer works well - except when there are identical values in `df.A.iloc[0]`.  `InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects`

Comment: @AGS is there another column or something to break the tie?  Or I can introduce randomness to break the tie.

Comment: @AGS updated again.  This will prefer original order when there is a tie

Comment: Any column would work - even the name in Column `D`, as these will be unique.